# How to disable rowToggler conditionally in Primefaces/JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I need to conditionally make the rowToggler in my datatable disabled. I have a column like this:

```
<p:column id="checkoutRowToggler">
            <div>
                <p:rowToggler/>
            </div>
</p:column>
```

I want to disable rowExpansion when FacesContext.isValidationFailed() returns true. Is there a way?

Using Primefaces 6/JSF.